# Could Truman's wife be considered to be a prostitute under the governing laws of California?

Tags: the-truman-show

In the movie "The Truman Show", the show takes place in the fictional town of Seahaven.  However this town is actually located in California.  One would assume that the governing laws of California would also govern Seahaven, even if indirectly.

The current laws of California regard prostitution as a crime.  If this is the case, wouldn't the actress Hannah Gill who is playing Meryl Burbank (Truman's wife) be guilty of prostitution as she is being paid to have sex with Truman as his "wife"?  One might argue that she is legally married to Truman but I do not believe this to be the case since 1) He does not even know where he "really" lives and 2) he does he even know her "real" name.  One may also argue that she is just having consensual sex but according to the film every time she sleeps with Truman she gets an extra $10,000.  That clearly indicates she is getting paid to sleep with Truman. On the same token couldn't Christof (or the corporation) be charged as her pimp?

Comment: you don't have to be legally married to have sex with someone. If anything, she's a porn star, not a prostitute.

Comment: I agree, it would be more related to pornography than prostitution.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is specifically asking about the application of laws to a movie character. This is probably better suited to a site for law specialists rather than film specialists.

Comment: *"One would assume that the governing laws of California would also govern Seahaven"* Why assume this? Isn't this already an imaginary universe, with such an [unrealistic premise](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/18100/can-a-corporation-really-adopt-a-person) as imprisoning a man since birth in a fake town for a TV show?

Comment: In a show that had a revenue greater than most countries or even US state GDP?

Comment: Also, the film was set 20 years into the future, 2020. Considering the show was running for decades, and how much money they had, they could have bought an exception from Cali law. Look at NYC being legally independent from NY State.

Comment: First you have to get over the "corporations can adopt kids"  hurdle.

Comment: I do not understand why Catija is voting to close my question because it has nothing to do with consulting law specialists.   I'm just asking a fun question looking for an answer that would seem to fit.  I did not even consider "she could be more like a porn star then a prostitute" and am only looking for a reasonable explanation in a fictional universe.  Thanks.

Comment: Your question literally says "under the laws of California". We are not lawyers. We do not know what those laws are or whether there is any cause for a suit.

Comment: @ Catija Wow you are persnickety.  What the heck are you supposed to say?  One would assume that there were laws in the fictional universe of Truman, and that Seahaven would either follow those laws or have their own.  I wanted to know if people thought what the Meryl Burbank was doing could be considered to be prostitution.  Brett and Kicker understood the spirit of my question.  It is good to see that someone around here did.  Thank you BrettFromLA and kicker86

Comment: According to the California Penal Code, *"653.20.  For purposes of this chapter, the following definitions apply: (a) "Commit prostitution" means to engage in sexual conduct for money or other consideration, but does not include sexual conduct engaged in as a part of any stage performance, play, or other entertainment open to the public."* Therefore the wife's acting in "The Truman Show" would not be considered prostitution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think so, since pornography is legal. The way I understand it, prostitution is illegal in California but paying people to have sex on camera is perfectly legal.

Comment: This answer doesn't make any sense, because they didn't in fact have sex on camera.  This is made clear in the movie.  When Meryl invites Truman to bed, there's a cut to a security guard viewer: "You never see anything..."

Answer (score 5):

The way that would have worked, if at all, and leaving aside Truman not knowing about the show, was as *Actors* and *contracts*. Let's say an actor decides to do a film. Contract states that actor must indulge in sexual scenes for the show, and if they do, they get an incentive/bonus for their 'performance'. This is legal, since it's still acting, consensual, and not prostitution since this is a pre-planned activity as part of a film (as opposed to two people indulging in sex with money involved).